# Why can't a recursive onended property of an oscillator be used to create a music sequencer?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Im curious why the oscillators onended method can't be used to create a music sequencer and why using the "[two clocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/)" method is better.

Here is a rough (kinda working ) code sketch of what I'm thinking.

```
var x = oscillator.onended = function() {
        oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
        oscillator.frequency.value = 0;
        oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
        oscillator.start(audioContext.currentTime);
        oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 0.000001);


        oscillator.onended = function() {

            if (Math.abs(item - audioContext.currentTime) >= 1) {
                if (tick === 8) {
                    tick = 1;

                } else {
                    item = audioContext.currentTime;
                    tick += 1;
                    sounds.kick.play();
                }


            }



            x()


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably doesn't quite work as you want because you can't depend on exactly when onended is fired.  There's probably going to be a random gap between when one oscillator stops and the next begins.

Comment: To clarify - Javascript events are not fired immediately, they're queued up.  And lots of other stuff is going on in that Javascript event loop - like rendering and layout and garbage collection - so it may not be fired at a consistent interval.  You're going to get janky timing this way.

Comment: I see, so my code solves the problem with scheduling events on the fly, but it doesn't solve the browser rendering/slow down issue